# swift: How can I set the body in the PUT request in the generated iOS sdk for aws-api-gateway?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, http, aws-api-gateway

Here is the code for PUT request where I want to send the tokenId to the api as JSON: How can I do that?

```
 public func paymentPut(tokenId: String) -> AWSTask<AnyObject> {
    let headerParameters = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",

        ]

    let queryParameters:[String:Any] = [:]

    let pathParameters:[String:Any] = [:]

    return self.invokeHTTPRequest("PUT", urlString: "***", pathParameters: pathParameters, queryParameters: queryParameters, headerParameters: headerParameters, body: nil, responseClass: nil)
}
```

I have tried set the body as this but my app crashes:

```
    let body: [String:Any] = ["token": tokenId]
```

After crashing, the error is :
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[_TtGCs26_SwiftDeferredNSDictionarySSP__ JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey]: unrecognized selector sent to class

Comment: where is the `self.invokeHTTPRequest ` code you've tried?

Comment: this code is generated by aws sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, So this might help some one in the future. This is how I solved it:
1) create an AWS data model

```
import Foundation   
import AWSCore
@objcMembers
public class TESTPaymentPUT : AWSModel {

var token: String?

public override static func jsonKeyPathsByPropertyKey() -> [AnyHashable : Any]!{
    var params:[AnyHashable : Any] = [:]
    params["token"] = "token"

    return params
}
}
```

2) Set these values in your view controller:

```
let tokenBody = TESTPaymentPUT()
tokenBody?.token = token
```

3) Call the API method and set the tokenBody as the parameter in your view controller:

```
API.client.paymentPut(body: tokenBody).continueOnSuccessWith { (_) -> Any? in
                return nil
            }
```

4) Change the API method :

```
public func paymentPut(body: TESTPaymentPUT?) -> AWSTask<AnyObject> {
    let headerParameters = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",

        ]

    let queryParameters:[String:Any] = [:]

    let pathParameters:[String:Any] = [:]

    return self.invokeHTTPRequest("PUT", urlString: "***", pathParameters: pathParameters, queryParameters: queryParameters, headerParameters: headerParameters, body: body, responseClass: nil)
}
```